# rm: cannot remove: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash

```
    max@serv$ whoami
    max
    max@serv$ ls -la ./defines.php 
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 max max 1985 2011-11-16 02:01 ./defines.php
    max@serv$ chmod 0777 ./defines.php 
    max@serv$ rm ./defines.php 
    rm: cannot remove `./defines.php': Permission denied
    max@serv$
```

How can I delete this file?

Comment: Is the file in the same directory you are running the command? then It should be only `rm defines.php`. why are you preppending the `./` ?

Comment: Other thing: It should be `chmod 777`

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. `file` and `./file` are equivalent.

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle - the octal mode is 1-4 digits, with missing digits assumed to be leading zeros. Therefore `chmod 777` and `chmod 0777` are identical.  Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

Comment: It might be that the directory was protected with `sticky bit`. You can check the directory permissions with `ls -ld`

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The code says everything:

```
max@serv$ chmod 777 .
```

Okay, it doesn't say everything.

In UNIX and Linux, the ability to remove a file is **not** determined by the access bits of that file. It is determined by the access bits of the directory which contains the file.

Think of it this way -- deleting a file doesn't modify that file. You aren't writing to the file, so why should "w" on the file matter? Deleting a file requires editing the directory that points to the file, so you need "w" on the that directory.

Comment: OMG! This answer gave me the solution to another problem, this same logic applies to read the files, not just delete.

Comment: i got this chmod: changing permissions of '.': Operation not permitted

Comment: That increases permissions for all to rwx, regardless of what it was before. Should be enough to add just the write permissions, and also refrain from adding permissions to group and others (unless that's how the user gets access to the directory to begin with); `chmod u+w .`