# Capistrano v3 not able to cleanup old releases

Tags: capistrano

Since I'm running my rails app as root, it creates files that are owned by root in the tmp directory. Because of this

```
cap production deploy:cleanup
```

can't remove old releases because it is not run as root.

I've looked at the capistrano v3 code, but I don't see a way to run the cleanup command as root. Is this option missing or is this problem occurring because I'm doing something wrong in another place of the deployment flow.

I start the app as root because I need to bind to port 80.

Answer (score 13):

What you can also do is triggering a task just before cleaning up the old release :

```
namespace :deploy do

  before :cleanup, :cleanup_permissions

  desc 'Set permissions on old releases before cleanup'
  task :cleanup_permissions do
    on release_roles :all do |host|
      releases = capture(:ls, '-x', releases_path).split
      if releases.count >= fetch(:keep_releases)
        info "Cleaning permissions on old releases"
        directories = (releases - releases.last(1))
        if directories.any?
          directories.each do |release|
            within releases_path.join(release) do
                execute :sudo, :chown, '-R', 'deployuser', 'path/to/your/files/writtend/by/root'
            end
          end
        else
          info t(:no_old_releases, host: host.to_s, keep_releases: fetch(:keep_releases))
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Note that you'll need to give your deployment user the right to execute this specific sudo command (with a `sudoers` definition file.

Comment: Most likely a micro-optimization unless you have a massive number of files, but you could just `rm` the directory in question immediately rather than doing `chmod`. Otherwise you're looping through the directory structure twice once `:cleanup` runs.

Answer (score 3):

> I've looked at the capistrano v3 code, but I don't see a way to run the cleanup command as root. Is this option missing or is this problem occurring because I'm doing something wrong in another place of the deployment flow.

There is no secret sauce in Capistrano, we rely on you having correctly set up the permissions for your deploy user as documented at http://www.capistranorb.com/

Removing directories requires `write` permissions on the parent directory, that is to say, given the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/releases/
              \- 20131015180000
              \- 20131015181500
              \- 20131015183000
```

You need *write* permission on the `/var/www/releases/` directory, as the list of files and directory in that directory, is stored in the directory.

From a [similar StackSverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175697/rm-cannot-remove-permission-denied):

> In UNIX and Linux, the ability to remove a file is not determined by the access bits of that file. It is determined by the access bits of the directory which contains the file.

From the [Wikipedia article on Unix File Permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions):

> The write permission grants the ability to modify a file. When set for a directory, this permission grants the ability to modify entries in the directory. This includes creating files, deleting files, and renaming files.

Comment: This won't solve the problem if the application creates any folders with files inside it. Then the folders under the release directory will be owned by root, so the deploying user won't be able to unlink their contents.

Comment: This can be solved by setting `setgid` on the release directory, and making sure that the application is running with `umask` `002`. The `setgid` will make sure that the `group` of the parent dir is copied to all files & directories created within it. The umask will ensure that the default access mode for new files and folders is the equivalent of `ug+rw`.

Comment: Yes, that was Coffee Bite's answer, but the umask is critical, and that's not always easy or safe. In a multithreaded server, setting umask can interfere with other threads. The cleanup and sudoer fix by foobar is safer.

Comment: I'd like to see a citation of umask being harmful in multi threaded situations, since it refers to file *creation*, I don't see a situation where different threads would end up with different umasks racing to create the same file. Processes forked by one with the correct umask will inherit it. If I'm wrong I'd sincerely like to be educated on this, as I've never seen it fail in the wild, and I recommend it to everyone who uses Capistrano. (I'm the maintainer)

Comment: If all the files the app creates use the same umask, it's not a problem. The issue arises when switching between different umasks. At least in PHP land (I recognize the original question was about Rails), the threads share a umask and thus one thread can alter it for another.

Comment: "POSIX.1 also requires that threads share a range of other attributes (i.e., these attributes are process-wide rather than per-thread): ... file mode creation mask (umask(2)))." (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting the citation, so slightly unusually if for some reason processes are changing the `umask` they should be doing it within a mutex. Well TIL.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you may want to do is to create a group called `app` or `web` on your linux box and add `root` and the `deploy` user to the same group. Then, as part of your deployment, `chmod` the `release_path` permissions to `g+s` which will ensure that any new files created by root user are group writable.

You should then be able to remove the old folders as `deploy` user.

Comment: This will only work if the application creates its files with a umask that includes the group write bit. The `setgid` bit that `g+s` specifies will only ensure that created files are owned the new shared group, not that they are writeable by that group.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar issues, so, to confirm, logged into my Web server via SSH, and tried `rm -rf [directory]`, which also failed due to the same permissions issues, even logged in as admin. Running `chmod -R 755 [directory]/`, then `rm -rf [directory]/` did work, though.

To fix it, in the project's silverstripe.rake file, I changed the command being run from:
`execute :chown, "-R [user]:[group] /path/to/project"`

to:
`execute :chmod, "-R 755 /path/to/project"`

So far, no more issues with deleting the oldest release when running `cap [release name] deploy`